# With Minecraft Windows 10 Edition, do I get a Mojang Account? Power of desktop Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

If I purchase Minecraft Windows 10 edition, do I get a Minecraft/Mojang account?
In other words, can I then play the older desktop edition as well?

(I know that the Windows 10 Minecraft is similar to Pocket Edition Minecraft. Advantages of the desktop edition include the ability to "mod", and the ability to load/save and share worlds.  I would like to have those capabilities on Windows 10.).

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Since Windows 10 Edition is very similar to Pocket Edition (the latter is missing one major update), you should check for questions about PE as well. I am pretty sure a question about using worlds from one in the other exists already.

Comment: @MrLemon Mojang has stated clearly that Win10 version IS Pocket Edition, but the changes haven't been made to all devices but will.

Comment: @ydobonebi I know, hence why I wrote that the difference is just that PE is lacking one major update (0.12).

Comment: You last edit should have been a comment instead.

Comment: You would be better off buying the Java edition, it has WAY more features, not just modding(Ex: Commands, desktop Settings, better UI for desktop, etc.)

Comment: According to PC Gamer the answer will become yes in 2022

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389361/can-you-get-minecraft-java-for-free-if-you-have-purchased-minecraft-bedrock)

Answer (score 0):

You get a free Minecraft for Windows 10 account if you already have a regular Minecraft account. You just have to go to the website and enter your credentials and then it will activate it for Windows 10.

You will not get an old account to play the old Minecraft however. You will have to buy the new one for $10, but the old one will cost another $20 or so.

Comment: Also possibly worth adding: mods are not currently supported, but Microsoft/Mojang are planning to implement them if possible.

Comment: @Jeeva I really wonder where they said that. That is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PC account you will receive a free copy of Win10 Version. You need to login to your Mojang account (not Minecraft account) and you will find a button marked 'redeem' Windows 10 version. If you buy it from the Windows store you do not (that I'm aware of) get a PC account. This is keeping with other Pocket Editions of the game.

To address your question about worlds. It does not appear that the world data is compatible. Win10 edition stores data using MSAccessDB where as PC version uses NBT data files.

It may be possible to convert in the future, but I couldn't find any such tool at this time. However, you should be able to transfer worlds between other MC Win10 versions (for example, I should be able to send you my Win10 world saves and they should, in theory, work just fine so long as you also use Win10 version)

Also, modding is not possible yet. Win10 version was a complete rewrite using C++ instead of Java. As such, they haven't included any mechanism to mod the game and typical techniques used with other versions won't work.

Mojang has stated they intend to make the game moddable in the future, however they haven't given a concrete timeline for this.

If you wish to have the ability to easily (relatively speaking) move worlds between users and play modded Minecraft you are better off acquiring a regular Minecraft account which will allow you to play Modded Minecraft as well normal Minecraft, and will also grant you a free copy of the MC for Win10.

Comment: 1) I posted a tweet asking MS to rewrite MC with C++, turns out they did read and listen to my advice. 2) I read that you can convert your PC maps to Mobile maps, with losing some blocks. I also read that W10 version uses mobile maps. You might be able to do the same with W10 too.

Comment: @ardaozkal 1) you are not that important and that is not the reasaon Win10 MC is in C++. It's a metro app, so the only real choices were C++ or any .Net compatible language (C#, VB, C++/CLI etc). Your comparison doesn't make sense. Yes, you could convert from PC to Mobile and only lose blocks because those blocks don't exists in mobile, same happens if you downconvert your PC maps. But W10 MC IS Mobile MC (MCPE) so they should be using the same world save modeling.

Comment: 1) I know, I was joking. They really do listen to bug reports etc tho. Also I know what Metro apps support. 2) That is what I said. It does make sense. Yes, there will be lost blocks, but it'll work.

Comment: @ydobonebi Do you have a source for your line on Minecraft Win 10 using MSAccessDB? Seems an unlikely / silly choice.

Comment: @kenjara The db file is in the save folder for the game. I agree there are more logical ways to store such data but being a metro app maybe they were limited in choices?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can't make Mojang accounts anymore

Comment: This question is from 2015, and has been already been answered. There is talk on Meta.SE of questions and answer versions, which might make your answer more on point.